# Configure lru_cache for class and static methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, lru

I am trying to use `lru_cache` in Python3 to speed up common queries into our Salesforce database. Below is the relevant code that is supposed to

- a) convert non-hashable arguments to hashable ones, and
- b) enable the LRU cache for those objects.

When I try this code, the cache works for calling the functions with no arguments, but it doesn't seem to cache the function calls with arguments. Also, I am not sure of how to order the decorators for the decorated functions.

Note, I am using a class here with class and static methods so I can override the `get` and `get_all` methods for different subclasses of `Resource`.

Please explain what I am doing wrong or could be doing better.

```
from functools import lru_cache
from functools import wraps

class Resource(object):

    def hash_dict(func):
        """Transform mutable dictionnary
           Into immutable
           Useful to be compatible with cache
        """
        class HDict(dict):
            def __hash__(self):
                return hash(frozenset(self.items()))

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            args = tuple([HDict(arg) if isinstance(arg, dict) else arg for arg in args])
            kwargs = {}
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    kwargs[k] = HDict(v)
                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    kwargs[k] = tuple(v)
                else:
                    kwargs[k] = v
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    @staticmethod
    @hash_dict
    @lru_cache
    def get(cls, resource_id, lang='en', fields=None):
        pass

    @classmethod
    @hash_dict
    @lru_cache
    def get_all(cls, lang='en', filters=None, fields=None):
        pass
```

Comment: `dict`s are unhashable on purpose, adding `__hash__` method implementation doesn't save you from possible mutation of `kwargs` inside of a wrapped method

Answer (score 18):

No need for an additional package. The following work as expected:

```py
import functools


class A:

  @staticmethod
  @functools.cache
  def build(value):
    print('Creating', value)
    return A()


assert A.build('a') is A.build('a')
assert A.build('b') is A.build('b')
assert A.build('b') is not A.build('a')
```

Starting python 3.9, you can replace `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)` by `@functools.cache`.

Answer (score 3):

This should be the answer you are looking for: https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#method-classmethod-staticmethod

`lru_cache` supports only simple functions. `Ring` gives very similar interface but including any kind of descriptor supports.

```
class Page(object):
    (...)

    @ring.lru()
    @classmethod
    def class_content(cls):
        return cls.base_content

    @ring.lru()
    @staticmethod
    def example_dot_com():
        return requests.get('http://example.com').content
```

See the link for more details. Note that the example is not LRU.

Answer (score 2):

IDK if I came to late for you, for here is my response. You got a couple of things wrong.

First, you are overwriting `args` and `kwargs` in `wapped` function definition. This is effectively deleting your function parameters.

Second, you only making inmutable lists in the `kwargs` case, not in `args`.

Also, `lru_cache` is a decorator constructor, so it must be called `@lru_cache()`. I don't know how it is working to you without it.

Besides, you are declaring `def get(cls, ...` function as a `@staticmethod`, then it wouldn't receive a `cls` argument.

But **most importantly**, defining a decorator inside a class isn't straightforward, as stated in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@vadimpushtaev/decorator-inside-python-class-1e74d23107f6). 
I get what you are trying to do: enforce caching by inheritance, and while it may seem a good idea, it will not work properly. If you override a function, you will have to redecorate it with cache again and this misses the point of declaring decorators inside a class.

To wrap it up, I would save myself problems and **declare the decorator in a different class** and using it elsewhere. But be careful, as caching class methods isn't straightforward either.

---

#### Extra:

I was some weeks ago in a similar situation, wanting to cache a function that accepts a numpy array. I came up with [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/Susensio/61f4fee01150caaac1e10fc5f005eb75) based on [this so response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331944/cache-decorator-for-numpy-arrays/52332109). I just transform the array into a tuple, and reconstruct it again (as I need it to be a mutable array at the end).

```
def np_cache(*args, **kwargs):
    """LRU cache implementation for functions whose FIRST parameter is a numpy array
    >>> array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
    >>> @np_cache(maxsize=256)
    ... def multiply(array, factor):
    ...     print("Calculating...")
    ...     return factor*array
    >>> multiply(array, 2)
    Calculating...
    array([[ 2,  4,  6],
           [ 8, 10, 12]])
    >>> multiply(array, 2)
    array([[ 2,  4,  6],
           [ 8, 10, 12]])
    >>> multiply.cache_info()
    CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=256, currsize=1)

    """
    def decorator(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(np_array, *args, **kwargs):
            hashable_array = array_to_tuple(np_array)
            return cached_wrapper(hashable_array, *args, **kwargs)

        @lru_cache(*args, **kwargs)
        def cached_wrapper(hashable_array, *args, **kwargs):
            array = np.array(hashable_array)
            return function(array, *args, **kwargs)

        def array_to_tuple(np_array):
            """Iterates recursivelly."""
            try:
                return tuple(array_to_tuple(_) for _ in np_array)
            except TypeError:
                return np_array

        # copy lru_cache attributes over too
        wrapper.cache_info = cached_wrapper.cache_info
        wrapper.cache_clear = cached_wrapper.cache_clear

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

while this does not directly solve your problem, it could be easily generalized for an arbitrary number of input arguments.