# Cache decorator for numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, caching, decorator

I am trying to make a cache decorator for functions with numpy array input parameters

```
from functools import lru_cache
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

@lru_cache()
def square(array):
    sleep(1)
    return array * array

square(a)
```

But numpy arrays are not hashable,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-559f69d0dec3> in <module>()
----> 1 square(a)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So they need to be converted to tuples. I have this working and caching correctly:

```
@lru_cache()
def square(array_hashable):
    sleep(1)
    array = np.array(array_hashable)
    return array * array

square(tuple(a))
```

But I wanted to wrap it all up in a decorator, so far I have tried:

```
def np_cache(function):
    def outter(array):
        array_hashable = tuple(array)

        @lru_cache()
        def inner(array_hashable_inner):
            array_inner = np.array(array_hashable_inner)
            return function(array_inner)

        return inner(array_hashable)

    return outter

@np_cache
def square(array):
    sleep(1)
    return array * array
```

But **caching is not working**. Computation is performed but not cached properly, as I am always waiting 1 second.

What am I missing here? I'm guessing `lru_cache` isn't getting the context right and its being instantiated in each call, but I don't know how to fix it.

I have tried blindly throwing the `functools.wraps` decorator here and there with no luck.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your wrapper function creates a **new `inner()` function** each time you call it. And that new function object is decorated at that time, so the end result is that each time `outter()` is called, a new `lru_cache()` is created and that'll be empty. An empty cache will always have to re-calculate the value.

You need to create a decorator that attaches the cache to a function created *just once* per decorated target. If you are going to convert to a tuple before calling the cache, then you'll have to create **two** functions:

```
from functools import lru_cache, wraps

def np_cache(function):
    @lru_cache()
    def cached_wrapper(hashable_array):
        array = np.array(hashable_array)
        return function(array)

    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(array):
        return cached_wrapper(tuple(array))

    # copy lru_cache attributes over too
    wrapper.cache_info = cached_wrapper.cache_info
    wrapper.cache_clear = cached_wrapper.cache_clear

    return wrapper
```

The `cached_wrapper()` function is created just once per call to `np_cache()` and is available to the `wrapper()` function as a closure. So `wrapper()` calls `cached_wrapper()`, which has a `@lru_cache()` attached to it, caching your tuples.

I also copied across the two function references that `lru_cache` puts on a decorated function, so they are accessible via the returned wrapper as well.

In addition, I also used the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to copy across metadata from the original function object to the wrapper, such as the name, annotations and documentation string. This is always a good idea, because that means your decorated function will be clearly identified in tracebacks, when debugging and when you need to access documentation or annotations. The decorator also adds a `__wrapped__` attribute pointing back to the original function, which would [let you unwrap the decorator again if need be](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.unwrap).

Comment: I want to add that you can share the array between wrapper() and cashed_wrapper() by assigning it to a nonlocal variable defined in np_cache(), so that the line 'array = np.array(hashable_array)' can be removed.

Comment: @Pulsar: no, you can't. It would not be thread-safe. You can't be certain that whatever is being passed to `cached_wrapper()` is tuple-value version of the same array. Any closure shared between the two should be treated like you would a global in the scope of each `function` being decorated.

Comment: Is it possible to make the decorator flexible (able to be used on many function with different number of arguments)?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to extend this to an arbitrary number of arguments of different types.

For that, you must check for each positional argument and keyword argument if it is of type numpy array and convert them to tuples. The other arguments you don't touch.

Before your function is called, you convert all tuples in the positional arguments and keywords arguments back to numpy arrays.

```
from typing import Callable
import numpy as np
from functools import cache, wraps


def np_cache(function):
    @cache
    def cached_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        args = [np.array(a) if isinstance(a, tuple) else a for a in args]
        kwargs = {
            k: np.array(v) if isinstance(v, tuple) else v for k, v in kwargs.items()
        }

        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [tuple(a) if isinstance(a, np.ndarray) else a for a in args]
        kwargs = {
            k: tuple(v) if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v for k, v in kwargs.items()
        }
        return cached_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.cache_info = cached_wrapper.cache_info
    wrapper.cache_clear = cached_wrapper.cache_clear

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting an array to a tuple is a slow and memory intensive operation. It loops over the entire array and builds a Python object from every array element. I think if your are concerned with memoization you want to avoid unnecessary computations.

You can avoid this by specifying your own hashing function for the array, which can use only some values, or only the shape, or whatever you specifically need.

This can be done building on top of [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) answer and using a wrapping class.

```py
    import hashlib
    import time
    
    import numpy as np
    
    from functools import lru_cache, wraps
    
    def expensive_function(x: np.array)-> float:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return np.sqrt(x.clip(1).sum())
    
    class YetAnotherWrapper:
        def __init__(self, x: np.array) -> None:
            self.values = x
            # here you can use your own hashing function
            self.h = hashlib.sha224(x.view()).hexdigest()
    
        def __hash__(self) -> int:
            return hash(self.h)
        
        def __eq__(self, __value: object) -> bool:
            return __value.h == self.h
    
    def memoizer(expensive_function):
        @lru_cache()
        def cached_wrapper(shell):
            return expensive_function(shell.values)
    
        @wraps(expensive_function)
        def wrapper(x: np.array):
            shell = YetAnotherWrapper(x)
            return cached_wrapper(shell)
    
        return wrapper
    
    
    a = np.random.random((1, 5))
    a = np.vstack((a, )* 200)
    
    memoized_expensive_function = memoizer(expensive_function)
    
    np.apply_along_axis(expensive_function, 1, a) # takes 20 seconds
    np.apply_along_axis(memoized_expensive_function, 1, a) # takes 0.2 seconds
```